# Jquery output link's alt on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to output the link's "alt" on hover. (Text is showing up in `#container` div).

This is what i have been trying so far (it doesnt work):

If you have any better ideas, please suggest.

**HTML**

```
<div><a href="#" class="heroes" alt="necromancer">Icon</a></div>

<div><a href="#" class="heroes" alt="witch">Icon</a></div>

<div><a href="#" class="heroes" alt="barbarian">Icon</a></div>

<div><a href="#" class="heroes" alt="troll">Icon</a></div>

<div id="container"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.container').hover(function() {
    var hero = $(this).attr('alt');
    $('#container').text(hero);
}, function() {
    $('#container').text("");
});
```

> **JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/XDky6/**

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.heroes').hover(function() {
    var hero = $(this).attr('alt');
    $('#container').text(hero);
}, function() {
    $('#container').text("");
});
```

`hover` should be called on `$('.heroes')`, not `$('.container')`.

Answer (score 1):

You misstyped your code.
You are reffering to the wrong class.

It should be `.heroes` but it's `.container`.

Fixed code :

```
    $('.heroes').hover(function() { 
    var hero = $(this).attr('alt'); 
    $('#container').text(hero); 
}, function() { 
    $('#container').text(""); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.heroes').hover(
 function() {
    var hero = $(this).attr('alt');
    $('#container').text(hero);
},
function() {
    $('#container').text("");}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/RdSCV/1/

Wrong class was passed i.e. correct class is `.heroes`

**code**

```
$('.heroes').hover(function() {
    var hero = $(this).attr('alt');
    $('#container').text(hero);
}, function() {
    $('#container').text("");
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

The initial selector is incorrect.  Change `.container` to `.heroes`

Answer (score 0):

If you can accept the `alt` text appearing next to the link, then:

```
<style>
a:hover:after {
  content: attr(alt);
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #bbb;
}
</style>
```